# How to get separate results for each underlying row in a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model like this:

```
Category:
    id (primary key)
    parent_id (foreign key)
    name (string)
```

And having a list of child categories ids I am querying their parents recursivelly with sqlalchemy common table expressions like this:

```
r = session.query(Category.id, Category.parent_id, *fields).\
    filter(Category.id.in_(id_list)).\
        cte(name='r', recursive=True)
r_alias = aliased(r, name="recursive")
base_alias = aliased(Category, name='base')
included_parts = r.union_all(
  session.query(base_alias).filter(base_alias.id == r_alias.c.parent_id)
)
q = session.query(included_parts).all()
print(q)
```

This is producing the following results (all parents of categories with id's [1, 2]:

```
[(1, None, 'Category1'), (2, 1, 'Category2'), (1, None, 'Category1')]
```

But I want to get a list for each category separatelly, what I need is something like this (separate results per id in id_list):

```
[
    [(1, None, 'Category1')],
    [(2, 1, 'Category2'), (1, None, 'Category1')]
]
```

Is there a way to do it or to make the groups more easily separable (for example is there a way to include the corresponding id from the id_list in each result so I can then group results by it) by SQLAlchemy means?

For example how to get the following results instead of the ones I'm getting:

```
[(1, 1, None, 'Category1'), (2, 2, 1, 'Category2'), (2, 1, None, 'Category1')]
```

then I would be able to group them by the first member of each tuple to get the desired groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to add the original ids as the first column in the originating SELECT and keep selecting those in the iterative steps of the recursive CTE:

```
In [18]: r = session.query(Category.id.label('orig_id'),
    ...:                   Category.id,
    ...:                   Category.parent_id,
    ...:                   *fields).\
    ...:     filter(Category.id.in_(id_list)).\
    ...:     cte(name='r', recursive=True)
    ...: 
    ...: r_alias = aliased(r, name="recursive")
    ...: base_alias = aliased(Category, name='base')
    ...: 
    ...: included_parts = r.union_all(
    ...:   session.query(r_alias.c.orig_id,  # Select the originating ID here
    ...:                 base_alias).
    ...:       filter(base_alias.id == r_alias.c.parent_id))
    ...:       
    ...: res = session.query(included_parts).all()
    ...: print(res)
    ...: 
[(1, 1, None, 'first'), (2, 2, 1, 'second'), (2, 1, None, 'first')]
```